# Erro ao retornar um DataTable de uma função que executa uma StoredProcedure em MySQL

Tags: datatable

Senhores.

Gostaria de Executar uma StoredProcedure em MySql
e o resultado retornar em um DataTable,
mas o retorno do DataTable não está dando certo.

Tenho uma conexão com o mysql:

```
public class Conexao
    private MySqlConnection conexao = null;
    private DataTable dt;
    private MySqlDataReader dr;

    string StrConexao = "server=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server_name"] + ";" +
                                  "dataBase=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["data_base"] + ";" +
                                  "port=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port_number"] + ";" +
                                  "User Id=root;" +
                                  "password=root";

    // Metodo conectar no banco.
    public MySqlConnection AbrirConexao()
    {
        try
        {
            conexao = new MySqlConnection(StrConexao);
            conexao.Open();
            return conexao;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw erro;
        }
    }
```

}

Conexão está funcionando porque utilizo ela em outro recurso.

Tenho uma Stored Procedure em MySql:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_seleciona_pessoa`()
BEGIN

```
select id, nome from pessoa;
```

END

Tenho uma função que retorna um DataTable:

```
public DataTable RetDataTableStoredProc()
```

{
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

```
            AbrirConexao();

            cmd.Connection = conexao;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "p_seleciona_pessoa";
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;
```

}

O comando dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); passa sem dar erro
mas quando executo as duas linhas abaixo:

```
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;
```

e não retorna um DataTable.

Conto com vossa ajuda.

Att.

Gilberto Rezende

Answer (score 0):

Sou grato, já resolvi o problema.

```
       try
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            cmd.Connection = conexao;
            cmd.CommandText = StoredProc;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "tabela");
            dt = ds.Tables["tabela"];
            return dt;

        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {

            throw erro;
        }
```

att.

Gilberto Rezende